# How to calculate the final value of a row based on another table with costs in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sum

I'm new to SQL and I have two tables like those in my PostgreSQL database:

table 1 - *building_specs*

```
+-----+---------+---------+--------+
| key | wallsId | floorId | roofId |
+-----+---------+---------+--------+
| 701 |    1    |    3    |    2   |
+-----+---------+---------+--------+
| 702 |    1    |    3    |    1   |
+-----+---------+---------+--------+
| 703 |    2    |    1    |    3   |
+-----+---------+---------+--------+
```

table 2 - *spec_value*

```
+-------+-------+-------+------+
| value | walls | floor | roof |
+-------+-------+-------+------+
|   1   |  4,8  |  5,4  |  3,6 |
+-------+-------+-------+------+
|   2   |  7,5  |  3,8  |  7,8 |
+-------+-------+-------+------+
|   3   |  3,6  |  10,1 |  4,1 |
+-------+-------+-------+------+
```

I need to calculate a final value for each `key` in *building_specs* based on the `values` of *spec_value*

For example, the `final_value` for the line 701 in Table 1:

-> `wallsId` = *1* -> Reffers to value *4.8* in Table 2, Column `walls`
-> `floorId` = *3* -> Reffers to value *10.1* in Table 2, Column `floor`
-> `roofId` = *2* -> Reffers to value *7.8* in Table 2, Column `roof`

Then, it should sum all referred values from table 2 and obtain a `final_value` of *22.7*

So, the kind of return I expect is like this:

```
+-----+-------------+
| key | final_value |
+-----+-------------+
| 701 |     22,7    |
+-----+-------------+
| 702 |     18,5    |
+-----+-------------+
| 703 |      17     |
+-----+-------------+
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You may want to explain how exactly you arrive at `final_value`s, as it's not at all obvious.

Comment: Sorry, just add'd how I got them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question right , you'll need something like

```
select bs.key , coalesce(w.walls,0) + coalesce(f.floor,0) + coalesce(r.roof,0) as final_value 
from building_specs bs 
left join spec_value w on w.value= bs.wallsId 
left join spec_value f on f.value= bs.floorId 
left join spec_value r on r.value= bs.roofId
```

Output matches 701 and 703 from the question , but different for 702 
(4.8 +10.1+3.6 != 12.2)

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot!

By the way, the value for 702 was a mistake I made, just corrected there.